# Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resourcev

Tags: php, mysql

So, I've been having alot of bother with a Paypal IPN script i'm working on - I'm a bit of an idiot when it comes to PHP.

I've got a script called glob.inc.php, which connects to my database and checks if a user is premium, however when the script is runs I just get this:

> Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result
>   resource in
>   /public_html/fts/rs_ipn/glob.inc.php
>   on line 11

This is the script for glob.inc.php:

```
 <?php
session_start();

// database connection
mysql_connect('XXXXXXXX','XXXXXXXX');
mysql_select_db('XXXXXXXX');

// premium check function
function is_premium() {
    $premium_query = mysql_query("SELECT 'premium' FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id'='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");
    $premium = mysql_result($premium_query, 0, 'premium');
    if ($premium =='1') {
    return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
 }

?>
```

I've tried everything I can think of, but am having no joy! May be interested to know that the script fails to successfully check if the user is premium. Sessions are created ok though, and the database connection is fine.

Hope you can help!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with PayPal, it's more about SQL 101: you are quoting table and column names and doing no error checking at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check that the query was executed properly?

See [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php).

Also, as mentioned in the comments, do not use mysql_* functions, use mysqli_* or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [fetch the result](http://www.php.net/mysql-fetch-row) instead of trying to access the resource.

Please refer to the documentation before asking question.